# 'Column not allowed here' in java program using Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

so I'm getting an error. Here is my output when I run this program and select query 1:

```
Connecting to the database...
The database connection was successful
Menu
Choose from the following:
 1. Add a new author
 2. Edit an existing author
 3. Add a new Title
 4. Add a new Author/Title combination
 5. Print databases
 6. Exit
 Make selection :  
1
 Enter author first name: 
oodewrw
 Enter author last name: 
asfsdf
Running query:
Creating statement...
SQL Error Message 1: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Menu
Choose from the following:
 1. Add a new author
 2. Edit an existing author
 3. Add a new Title
 4. Add a new Author/Title combination
 5. Print databases
 6. Exit
 Make selection : 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at ConnectAndRunQueries.getInput(ConnectAndRunQueries.java:154)
    at ConnectAndRunQueries.driver(ConnectAndRunQueries.java:94)
    at ConnectAndRunQueries.main(ConnectAndRunQueries.java:69)
```

Ignoring that i'm also getting a null exception pointer for now, I'm confused on why I'm getting the column error. From what I can tell, Oracle usually thinks anything not in quotes is a column. But since it's a Java program, I'm using variables instead of strings, so I don't want to put them in quotes.

**Other things I've tried**: using all caps in my program, playing with the concatenation, putting variables in quotes anyway, adding a number and doing a full insert instead of a partial insert, manually connecting to SQLPLUS and typing "INSERT INTO Authors  VALUES <'Me', 'Julie'>; (I get back "one row created".)

Why does my program see variables as a column insertion?

Here is my code:

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;


public class ConnectAndRunQueries {

private final static String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@coisor.austincc.edu:1527:CSOR";
private final static String dbUser = "user";
private final static String dbPasswd = "password";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;

public int choice = 0;
public String firstName;
public String lastName;
public int authorID;
public int ISBN;
public String title;
public int editionNumber;
public String copyright;
public Boolean quit = false;
public ResultSet resultSet = null;
public Boolean weAreOkay = false;
public String query = null;
public int numberOfColumns = 0;


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    try {
        // Load the driver class
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Failed to load SQL driver." + e);
       return;
    }

    ConnectAndRunQueries myObject = new ConnectAndRunQueries();
    myObject.driver();
}    

public void driver() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("\nConnecting to the database...");
        testConnectToDb();

        getInput();

        while (!quit)
        {
             createQueries();

             System.out.println("Running query:");
             runQueries(query);

             if (choice == 5)
             {
                 displayQueries();
                 choice = 5;
                 createQueries();
                 runQueries(query);
             }

             getInput();
        }    

    System.out.println("Closing the Database Connection...");
        closeDBConnection();
    }


private boolean testConnectToDb()
{
    boolean rtnCode = false;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPasswd);
        if(connection != null)
        {
            rtnCode = true;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (rtnCode)
         System.out.println("The database connection was successful");
     else
         System.out.println("The database connection was Not successful");

    return rtnCode;
}

// Close the Database connection.
private void closeDBConnection() throws Exception, SQLException
{
    try
    {
        if (statement != null)
           statement.close();
        if (connection != null)
           connection.close();  // Close the database connection
    } 
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

private void getInput()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Menu");
      System.out.println("Choose from the following:");
      System.out.println(" 1. Add a new author");
      System.out.println(" 2. Edit an existing author");
      System.out.println(" 3. Add a new Title");
      System.out.println(" 4. Add a new Author/Title combination");
      System.out.println(" 5. Print databases");
      System.out.println(" 6. Exit");
      System.out.println(" Make selection : ");
      Integer input1 = scanner.nextInt();
      //scanner.close();


     if (input1 == 1)
      {      
        System.out.println(" Enter author first name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" Enter author last name: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();
        choice = 1;
        input.close();
      }

     if (input1 == 2)
     {
        System.out.println(" Enter authorID: ");
        authorID = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(" Enter author first name: ");
        firstName = input.nextLine();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(" Enter author last name: ");
        lastName = input.nextLine();
        choice = 2;
        input.close();
      }

     if (input1 == 3)
     {
         System.out.println(" Enter ISBN number: ");
         ISBN = input.nextInt();
         System.out.println(" Enter Title: ");
         title = input.nextLine();
         input.nextLine();
         System.out.println(" Enter Edition Number: ");
         editionNumber = input.nextInt();
         System.out.println(" Enter Copyright year: ");
         copyright = scanner.nextLine();
         input.nextLine();
         System.out.println(" Enter authorID: ");
         authorID = scanner.nextInt();
         choice = 3;
         input.close();
     }

     if (input1 == 4)
     {
         System.out.println(" Enter authorID: ");
         authorID = scanner.nextInt();
         System.out.println(" Enter ISBN number: ");
         ISBN = scanner.nextInt();
         choice = 4;
         input.close();
     }

     if (input1 == 5)
     {
       choice = 5;
     }

     if (input1 == 6)
     {
       quit = true;        
     }
     return;

  } 

private void createQueries()
{
    //INSERT INTO Authors
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        query =  "INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName, LastName)" + "VALUES (firstName, lastName) ";
    }

    //UPDATE authors
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        query = "UPDATE Authors " +
                " SET FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName " +
                " WHERE AuthorID = authorID) ";
    }

    //INSERT title
    if (choice == 3)
    {
        query = "INSERT INTO Titles (ISBN, Title, EditionNumber, Copyright)" +
                " VALUES (ISBN, title, editionNumber, copyright) ";
    }
    //INSERT INTO AuthorISBN
    if (choice == 4)
    {
        query = "INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID, ISBN)" +
                " VALUES (authorID, ISBN) ";
    }

    if (choice == 5)
    {
        query = "SELECT AuthorID, FirstName, LastName FROM Authors";
    }

    if (choice == 6)
    {
        query = "SELECT ISBN, Title, EditionNumber, Copyright FROM Titles";
    }
}

private void runQueries(String queryToRun)throws Exception, SQLException
{

    String sqlMessage = null;

    // Execute the query and get our result
    try {
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryToRun);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        if (e != null)
            sqlMessage = e.getMessage();

        System.out.println("SQL Error Message 1: " + sqlMessage);
        return;
    } 

    try {
        // process query results
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("Table of Books Database:\n");

        // display row set header
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
            System.out.printf("%-8s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i));
        System.out.println();

        // display each row
        while (resultSet.next()) 
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
                System.out.printf("%-8s\t", resultSet.getObject(i));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        weAreOkay = false;
        if (e != null)
            sqlMessage = e.getMessage();

        System.out.println("SQL Error Message 2: " + sqlMessage);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

public void displayQueries() throws Exception, SQLException
{
    String sqlMessage = null;
    ResultSetMetaData metaData;
    try
    {
        metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int numberOfColumns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
            System.out.printf("%-16s\t", metaData.getColumnName(i),"%n");

        while (resultSet.next() && weAreOkay)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
                System.out.printf("%-16s\t", resultSet.getObject(i));
            System.out.println();
        }   
    } 
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        weAreOkay = false;
        if (e != null) sqlMessage = e.getMessage();

        System.out.println("SQL Error Message 2: " + sqlMessage);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Your `insert` and `update` queries do not have any substitution placeholders.  What do you think `INSERT INTO Authors (FirstName, LastName)  VALUES (firstName, lastName)` is going to use for the values?  Also you're missing some spaces in your query strings.  Please review the tutorial on using JDBC and parameterized queries for help.

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you have a link? I've just googled "JDBC and parametized queries" and I get back the idea that I need to use prepared statements. Does that seem like the right track?

Comment: What happens if you Google "Oracle JDBC Tutorial"?

Comment: this is good: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html. I'm fuzzy on how to use resultSet methods except when using SELECT but I'll keep plugging away at it

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how you can create a parameterised statement with JDBC:

```
// Use the try-with-resources statement to properly manage resources in Java
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(

    // Use ? parameter markers in prepared statements
    "INSERT INTO AuthorISBN (AuthorID, ISBN) VALUES (?, ?)"
)) {

    // Prior to executing the statement, you have to bind actual values to the parameters
    stmt.setInt(1, authorID);
    stmt.setInt(2, ISBN);

    // Again, use try-with-resources
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {

        // Now, do your thing.
    }
}
```

Do not use a "static statement" (`Connection.createStatement()`) when embedding user input in your queries, for these two reasons:

- [SQL injection](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/05/using-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-to-dump-your-database/)
- [Performance](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/12/why-sql-bind-variables-are-important-for-performance/) (perhaps not applicable in your simple application)